# Can you record two MediaRecorder video streams at once?

Tags: java, android

We are looking at writing an Android app and we need to create two copies of the video that we record. Each one will require different settings (dimensions, etc). One will be a 'high quality' version (1280x720, high bitrate) and one will be a 'low quality' version (480x360, lower bitrate). Both will be mp4 files.

We have found that using MediaRecorder to record the higher quality version and then using ffmpeg to convert the video afterwards into the lower quality version is **excruciatingly** slow. We are getting speeds of something like 6 minutes for a 22 second video to be converted!

So is it possible to have two instances of MediaRecorder at once so that the stream is captured and encoded into the file on-the-fly, saving us the need to encode it after it's completed?

Alternatively are there any other suggestions as to how we can achieve this, or maximise ffmpeg's performance?

Comment: Just confirming that you are trying to compress a video into two different resolutions on an android device, at the same time?

Comment: Well I want to record a video and end up with 2 files, one high and one low quality. But converting with ffmpeg is far too slow, so I was thinking is it possible to just capture it from the camera and encode it on-the-fly?

We can get both videos fine individually, by changing the settings on MediaRecorder, but we can't get them both at once!

Comment: Working with video is very CPU intensive. Unless you are running on a brand new, quad core device, it might be impossible to do this in real time.

Comment: Ah I see.. that's a big shame. Can you think of any other way to do this? And is it actually possible to record twice? Perhaps we could benchmark it ourselves if you can suggest actually how to do it. As I understand it, it locks the camera if you record it one time doesn't it?

Comment: The only thing I can think of is leave whatever the camera outputs as the high quality version (i.e. don't try to encode it, just save it like a normal video). After the fact, you could compress it down to the smaller size. If that works successfully, you could try compressing it down in real time.

Comment: We do currently leave the camera output as the main, high quality video and then convert it down again to the lower quality version. ffmpeg is just far too slow on this for some reason. It seems to relate to CPU on the device but even on a brand new quad-core HTC One it still takes 6 minutes to convert a 30 second video!

Comment: In that case, you probably can't do it in real time. Sorry :(